# Intuition and physical meaning of Crystal Momentum and Effective mass of quasi-particles in Solids

Tags: mass, momentum, solid-state-physics, crystals, quasiparticles

I have read various questions related to mine on StackExchange and articles on Wikipedia and some other sources but I still can't get an intuition for the quantities "Crystal Momentum" and "Effective mass" of quasiparticles in a periodic potential. I am not taking a solid-state physics course, but this is a part of course on Quantum Mechanics where we are covering the theory of solids and periodic potentials. So, in such potentials, if we have a particle with an Energy spectrum $E(q)$ and the group velocity $v_g=\frac{1}{\hbar}\frac{\partial E(q)}{\partial q}$, then we observe the following -

- If we apply a constant force $F$ on the system, then $F=\frac{d(\hbar q)}{dt}$ where $\hbar q$ is the crystal momentum.
- The effective mass of a particle experiencing such a force $F$ is ${m_*}=(\frac{1}{\hbar^2}\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial q^2})^{-1}$

Even after knowing these mathematical facts, that the interaction of the electron with the potential causes an effective mass to arise and that crystal momentum is "kind" of a momentum because it is its rate of change is equal to the classical force. But this doesn't offer a good enough intuition on what it actually is.

Is the crystal momentum $\hbar q$ a momentum of the quasi-particle of effective mass $m_*$? Or is it something else altogether? Any sort of help is appreciated.